# What happen to Subsonic...seen like no futhere development

Tags: subsonic

It has been a long time since Subsonic have stopped at version 3. Any new development going on? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We're releasing version 3.1 soon. If you take a look at the github repository at http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0 you'll see that the project is not dead at all. You'll find a roadmap for 3.1 (scattered over a couple of threads) on google groups http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject

Answer (score 2):

The github repos have very little activity and the referenced url for the website is dead (goes to a parked domain). Safe to say Subsonic is most likely dead at this point.

The original author of Subsonic, robconery, has created Massive, a micro-ORM implementation using the new dynamic keyword.  [While not necessarily intended to replace Subsonic](http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive), this is where development effort by him appears to be going.

Comment: And perhaps Entity Framework is seen as the "replacement" for the original concept of SubSonic - an ORM for C# development.