# C# .NET ORM SubSonic concerns

Tags: orm, subsonic

I am checking out a couple of ORMs for our C# .NET application. For what we want to accomplish, heavier-weight ones like NHibernate or Fluent NHibernate seem like overkill, for what we want to do. Something like SubSonic seems about the right fit; there's going to be overhead in configuration areas of one size or shape or another, only how much overhead can we sustain and stay focused on the application task at hand is the question. Also, with SubSonic, I am somewhat concerned the author(s) haven't updated it in what seems like over a year? Either it is fairly mature and works for most of what you'd want to do, or it has been abandoned? Which is another concern, keeping a community tool up to date. Any thoughts? SubSonic? Or similar type product?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be asked with some regularity.

[What happen to Subsonic...seen like no futhere development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975426/what-happen-to-subsonic-seen-like-no-futhere-development)

[Is SubSonic dying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037051/is-subsonic-dying)

I don't know that it's the right question to be asking.  If you are trying to decide on a .NET ORM, this question is more useful:

[NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/)

Depending on what version of .NET you are using, there aren't really that many good choices.  If you are using .NET 3.5, NHibernate is clearly the best choice.  If you are using .NET 4, choose between NHibernate or Entity Framework.

If it seems like NHibernate is "heavier weight", that is likely for one of two reasons:

1) the starter documentation / experience isn't as pleasant as it could be
2) it actually does a decent job of solving any issues you would run into because it's so feature rich

The fact is that Entity Framework will get you going faster with it's designer and code generation, but it's not really better than NHibernate and there is a significant learning curve with both.  See the link above for more helping deciding between the two if you are on .NET 4.

Subsonic is just okay as an ORM.  It may fit your needs, but NHibernate and Entity Framework are both being more actively developed and seem to have brighter futures.